# Add a range of items to the beginning of a list?

Tags: c#, .net, list, collections, sequence

The method `List<T>.AddRange(IEnumerable<T>)` adds a collection of items to the end of the list:

```
myList.AddRange(moreItems); // Adds moreItems to the end of myList
```

What is the best way to add a collection of items (as some `IEnumerable<T>`) to the beginning of the list?

Comment: Which ways have you tried? And what makes you think there's something better than that?

Comment: One glance at the available methods list would answer that question...

Comment: Sorry, I never thought to look at `Insert..`.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Use [InsertRange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/884ee1fz.aspx) method:

```
 myList.InsertRange(0, moreItems);
```

Answer (score 4):

Use [InsertRange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/884ee1fz.aspx) method:

```
 List<T>.InsertRange(0, yourcollection);
```

Also look at [Insert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sey5k5z4.aspx) method which you can add an element in your list with specific index.

> Inserts an element into the List at the specified index.

```
List<T>.Insert(0, T);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
List<String> listA=new List<String>{"A","B","C"};
List<String> listB=new List<String>{"p","Q","R"};

listA.InsertRange(0, listB);
```

Here suppose we have 2 list of string... then using the InsertRange method we can pass the starting index where we want to insert/push the new range(listB) to the existing range(listA)

Hope this clears the code.

Comment: Rather than only post a block of code, please *explain* why this code solves the problem posed. Without an explanation, this is not an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Please try `List<T>.InsertRange(0, IEnumerable<T>)`

Comment: some explanation will help this answer